# Adding multiple XmlElement.LastChild.InnerText

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I have a function where I want to add multiple **'values'** to a node. Here is function:

```
 private void GetCategory(DataRow reader, XmlElement myNode)
    {
        foreach (DataRow categoryRow in reader.GetChildRows("Article_Category"))
        {
            myNode.LastChild.InnerText = categoryRow["CATEGORY_NAME"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

myNode.OuterXml looks like this:

```
<field itemid="{2C16342E-7662-432B-9895-5EDB15914D7F}" language="en" version="1" 
fieldid="{1F5956D6-EABE-4F74-A248-B25B7EE90350}" name="Categories" title=""
type="Multilist" source="/sitecore/content/data/Categories" section="Content" 
tooltip=""><value>US</value></field>
```

I wanted to look something like this:

```
<field itemid="{2C16342E-7662-432B-9895-5EDB15914D7F}" language="en" version="1" 
fieldid="{1F5956D6-EABE-4F74-A248-B25B7EE90350}" name="Categories" title=""
type="Multilist" source="/sitecore/content/data/Categories" section="Content" 
tooltip=""><value>US</value><value>China</value><value>India</value></field>
```

I added this function:

```
 foreach (DataRow categoryRow in reader.GetChildRows("Article_Category"))
        {
            var newNode = myNode.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("Value");
            newNode.InnerText = categoryRow["CATEGORY_NAME"].ToString();
            myNode.AppendChild(newNode);

        }
```

Its does not work becoz this is how my XML looks like:

```
 <field itemid="{9259D344-3500-4887-9CDF-F00876F20F2B}" language="en" version="1"
 fieldid="{1F5956D6-EABE-4F74-A248-B25B7EE90350}" name="Country" title="" 
 type="Multilist" source="/sitecore/content/data/Countries" section="Content"
 tooltip=""><value /><Value>Currency Markets</Value></field>
```

THere is a **'value'** tag which does not lets add up.

Comment: Well, does "Article_Category" point to "US" and "China" or to "Currency Markets"? And the empty node is another issue.

Comment: Article_Category points to US/China/Currency Markets. Basically they are categories. I just defined them as Countries :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code overwrites the Text of the LastChild. You need to add nodes,

```
    //untested
    foreach (DataRow categoryRow in reader.GetChildRows("Category"))
    {
      //myNode.LastChild.InnerText = categoryRow["CATEGORY_NAME"].ToString();

        var newNode = myNode.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("value");
        newNode.InnerText = categoryRow["CATEGORY_NAME"].ToString();
        myNode.AppendChild(newNode);
    }
```

Comment: I added this line:             myNode.RemoveChild(myNode.LastChild);